# Sorting 2 excels into 1

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

There is n number of excel sheets which contain n number of worksheets in each .
Need:
need to combine all the worksheets of each excel into single excel in ascending order using macros

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean Excel workbooks with several worksheets in each?  If this is the case, right click the tab you want to copy to a new destination, click "Move or Copy..." and follow the instructions to copy to a new book.  Be sure to check the "Create a copy" box if you want to retain the worksheet in its original location as well as making a copy.

Just to be clear, you can then name this new workbook and move or copy other tabs to it.

Comment: You could record the steps I outlined if you wanted an non-VBA solution (I assumed this, for some reason) into a macro, and the steps were the same each time.  However, I have to admit I prefer Pav.s way :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need, it lets you choose your folder and then loops through all files in it and combines all sheets from those workbooks into a single one saved in the same directory. Does not sort though, but you can [find multiple ready macros](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sort%20sheets%20in%20workbook&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=rtXjV9_CL8Tv8AfWy4ToBQ#safe=active&q=vba%20sort%20sheets%20in%20workbook) to do it so just run one on the result or paste their content before mine wb2 save & close.

```
Sub MergeFilesWithoutSpaces()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim path As String

'pick folder
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'create new workbook to store results and rename its sheet
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
End With
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add
wb2.Worksheets(1).Name = "00Delete_Me"

'fetch filename
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
'loop through all *XLS files
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        'copy each worksheet
        For Each Sh In Wkb.Sheets
            Sh.Copy After:=wb2.Sheets(wb2.Sheets.Count)
        Next Sh

        Wkb.Close False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
'delete the initial sheet and save result as "combined" workbook in same directory
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb2.Sheets("00Delete_Me").Delete
wb2.SaveAs Filename:=(path & "\combined"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'close combined
wb2.Close
End Sub
```